# Get Data from url()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get `id` and `val` from this url()  and assign it to a text box
`http://localhost:59113/Project/ProjectAllocation/?id=9%20&val=%20dgds`

 I tried this code but am getting text box value like this`val=%20dgds,%20dgds`

```
  var url = document.URL;
var id = /id=([^&]+)/.exec(url);
var val = /val=([^&]+)/.exec(url);
var result = id ? id : ' ';
var result = getId()
 $('.currentProjectName').val(val)
```

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the URI

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:59113/Project/ProjectAllocation/?id=9%20&val=%20dgds;'
var id = decodeURI(/id=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]);
var val = decodeURI(/val=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]);
$('#txtid').val(id);
$('#txtval').val(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtid" value="">
<input type="text" id="txtval" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from this

```
function a() {debugger
    var url = document.URL;
    var param = getUrlParam("id");
    var param = getUrlParam("val");
    $('.currentProjectName').val(param)
}

function getUrlParam(param) {
    param = param.replace(/([\[\](){}*?+^$.\\|])/g, "\\$1");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)");
    var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    var match = regex.exec(url);
    return match ? match[1] : "";
}
```